# Are two projective schemes isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism between a cover by affines?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two schemes and suppose that $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a cover by affines of $X$ and $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a cover by affines of $Y$ and supposes there exists isomorphism
$$f_i: U_i \to V_i$$

Since any projective scheme is glued out of its affine cover it seems that this should be enough to conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.

I find gluing constructions a bit hard to digest but it seems that the only way that $X$ and $Y$ would not be isomorphic is if there individual gluing functions,

$$ g_{ij}: U_{ij} \to U_{ij} $$
$$h_{ij}: V_{ij} \to V_{ij}$$

are somehow not compatible. How are $g_{ij}$ and $h_{ij}$ related if $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic?

Comment: This is almost certainly not true, I think $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ should give a counterexample.

Comment: See the section "The glueing of morphisms" in [this document][1]. This gives a condition when $f_i$ glue to a single map of schemes. Then it can be checked locally on the target that this map is an isomorphism.


  [1]: http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4215/v15/notes3.pdf

Comment: I don't think @user45878's (nice) example quite does what we want: the projective plane can be covered with 3 affine planes, whereas I think one needs 4 for the product of the projective lines. But  what about a non-trivial ${\mathbb P}^1$ bundle $E$ over $ {\mathbb P}^1$? e..g., ${\mathbb P} ({ \cal O} \oplus  {\cal O}(1) )$?   One still has to show that $E$ and $ {\mathbb P}^1\times {\mathbb P}^1$ are not isomorphic as schemes (even if this idea is correct).